# Understanding Julia Int overflow behaviour

Tags: julia

Coming from a Python / Matlab background, I'd like to understand better how Julia's Int64 overflow behaviour works.

From the [documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/integers-and-floating-point-numbers/#Overflow-behavior):

> In Julia, exceeding the maximum representable value of a given type
> results in a wraparound behavior.

```
julia> x = typemax(Int64)
9223372036854775807

julia> x + 1
-9223372036854775808
```

Now, I did some experiments with numbers obviously larger than typemax(Int64), but the behaviour I see isn't consistent with the documentation. It seems like things don't always just wrap around. Is only a single wraparound allowed?

```
julia> x = (10^10)^(10^10)
0
julia> x = 10^10^10^10 
1   # ??

julia> x = 10^10^10^10^10  
10  # I'd expect it to be 1? 1^10 == 1?

julia> x = 10^10^10^10^10^10 
10000000000  # But here 10^10 == 10000000000, so now it works?


julia> typemax(Int64) > 10^19
true
julia > typemax(Int64) > -10^19
true
```

Can anyone shed light on the behaviour I am seeing?

**EDIT:**

Why does 9 overflow correctly, and 10 doesn't?

```
julia> 9^(10^14)
-1193713557845704703
julia> 9^(10^15)
4900281449122627585
julia> 10^(10^2)
0
julia> 10^(10^3)
0
```

Julia 0.5.0 (2016-09-19)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are seeing the result of PEMDAS order of operations, specifically the parenthesis before exponentiation portion. This effectively becomes a right-to-left solving of these expressions.

```
julia> 10^(10^10) #happens to overflow to 0
0

julia> 10^(10^(10^10)) # same as 10 ^ 0
1

julia> 10^(10^(10^(10^(10^10)))) # same as x = 10^(10^(10^(10^(10000000000)))) -> 10^(10^(10^(0))) -> 10^(10^(1)) -> 10^ 10
10000000000
```

So it's really just a matter of working through the arithmetic. Or realizing you are going to have such large operations that you start using BigInt from the outset.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That makes a lot of sense. Yet why does 10^(10^10) overflow to 0, and doesn't simply wrap around? 10^(10^11) also overflows to 0. And if you try 9^(10^14), 9^(10^15), you'll see things wrapping around as they should.

Comment: @dangom It does wrap around. `10^10^10` is a multiple of `2^64` and so happens to wrap around to `0`. The same happens with any large exponent of an even number, like `6^666` or `14^5^5`.

Comment: @FengyangWang  Indeed. I wouldn't have expected that. Thanks for the comment. [Is 10^100 a multiple of 2^64?](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=is+10%5E100+a+multiple+of+2%5E64)

Comment: @dangom Think of expanding everything in prime factors (10 = 2 x 5) to get your answer.